# nodejs require is not a function to js file

Tags: javascript, node.js, require

I want to make a little chat app for learning and I created many js files which for separate like modular but I got some error.

> this is my boot.js file

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

var admin = io.of('/app'),
    client = io.of('');

module.exports.app = app;
module.exports.http = http;
module.exports.io = io;
```

> this is my routes.js file

```
module.exports = {
    start: function(app) {
        app.get('/', function(req, res) {
            res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
        });
    }
};
```

> this is my chat.js

```
var boot = require('./boot');

require('./routes')(boot.app).start();

http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

> when i run the node i got this error

```
require('./routes')(boot.app).start();
                   ^
TypeError: require(...) is not a function
```

how could I use the variables which in the boot.js to other js files?

help me please.

Comment: shouldn't it be `require('./routes').start(boot.app);`

Comment: Seems like you are doing too many things in a single line. require is not async. Make sure express is initialzed before you require it

Comment: works thank you so much :)

Answer (score 2):

You are making a small mistake here. Below is the correct one.

```
require('./routes').start(boot.app);
```

`routes` module exports an object where you can call `start` and use that function.